# How to get the supported image formats that the method ImageIO.write can export?

Tags: java, image, format

Is there any way that I could get the supported image formats that the [ImageIO.write()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write-java.awt.image.RenderedImage-java.lang.String-java.io.File-) function can export ?

Comment: did you just ask a question and answer it?

Comment: Read [the javax.imageio package documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html#package.description).

Comment: @ItamarGreen it is a good practice to answer your own question and it is encouraged by the stackexchange community. For more information you can check this link [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: I still do not understand the negative voting. There are many questions in stackoverflow that have a simple answer, so simple that someone can see it in the documentation. Nevertheless, these questions have positive votes (for example this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java) has many positive votes).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getWriterFormatNames--) method.

Description of the method from the official javadocs:

> Returns an array of Strings listing all of the informal format names
>   understood by the current set of registered writers.